# How to increase HMM score on training samples with `hmmlearn`

Tags: python, hmmlearn

[Speech Recognizer for 7 fruits](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-Real-World-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Module%201/Chapter%207/speech_recognizer.py) (source code)
GaussianHMM is used. Each 7 classes has balanced dataset, precisely 15 audios per class. I have tried using 3-5 states but the scores are still low. All other settings are default, which is the ergodic HMM.

I understand that the score `score = hmm_model.get_score(mfcc_features)` returns the log likelihood of the observation, but surprisingly it is negative, `-1101.0923021`.

The probability is `np.exp(-1101.0923021) ~= 0`, which I think is unlikely as I test with one sample of the training data.

E.g.: Apple HMM score for apple.wav is `-1101.0923021`.

Are there ways to increase the score to make a more reliable model? Do I do a grid search on the number of components/hidden layer?

(P.S : Although the scores are low, it does predicts quite well)

Comment: We are missing info to help on this question. Can you share the code of how you trained the HMMs? (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It will make clear what is `X`.

Comment: @Eskapp Thanks for your kind advice! I have included the link.

Comment: How many samples are there in the training set? Also are the 7 classes balanced? Also, how many states does the HMM has? Is it a discrete, Gaussian HMM? I do not have time to go through the entire source code.

Comment: @Eskapp I have added the extra information. ;)

Comment: If you are training a unique HMM for the 7 classes then the log-likelihood will not tell you a lot about the class of the tested sample. You need to train a different HMM for each class. Then compute the log-likelihood of the test sample with respect to the 7 models and label the test sample with the model giving the highest likelihood result. Is that what you have done?

Comment: yes. I built an HMM for each class.

Comment: As you work with speech, I would suggest the use of a left-to-right HMM (opposite to fully connected). That would be my first try to improve the results.